# re.search() if result is None

Tags: python

How to make this pythonic?

```
def money_from_string(s):
    gold = re.search("([0-9]+)g", s)
    silver = re.search("([0-9]+)s", s)
    copper = re.search("([0-9]+)c", s)
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+g", "", s)
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+s", "", s)
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+c", "", s)
    assert (len(s.strip()) == 0) # should be 0

    return (gold.group() or 0) * 10000 + (silver.group() or 0) * 100 + (copper.group() or 0)
```

This doesn't work because if `gold` is `None`, `gold.group()` will throw an error.

Input examples & expected outputs:

```
s = "15g17s5c" -> 150000 + 1700 + 5 -> 151705
s = "15g5s"    -> 150000 + 500      -> 150500
s = "15g"      -> 150000            -> 150000
s = "17s5c"    -> 1700 + 5          -> 1705
s = "5c"       -> 5                 -> 5
```

Note that I do appropriate checks on the input, to ensure that it actually is of correct format. Ie. it has match:

```
MONEY_PATTERNS = [
    "([0-9]+g[ ]*[0-9]+s[ ]*[0-9]+c)", # g / s / c
    "([0-9]+g[ ]*[0-9]+s)", # g / s
    "([0-9]+g[ ]*[0-9]+c)", # g / c
    "([0-9]+s[ ]*[0-9]+c)", # s / c
    "([0-9]+g)", # g
    "([0-9]+s)", # s
    "([0-9]+c)", # c
]
```

Comment: You want something other than checking if it's `None` and returning something different?

Comment: What does `s` look like? I can guess from your code but I shouldn't have to

Comment: I'd worry about it being correct before it being pythonic.

Comment: Why not just use `obj.attr if obj else default`? I'd say that's as Pythonic as it gets. Or are you asking for a solution specific to `re.search`?

Comment: Also, note that `(gold.group() or 0)` etc. will return either a `str` or an `int`. Probably not what you want.

Comment: This question is not clear. We don't know what you're trying to accomplish if `gold` is None. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I have edited it to show some input & expected output examples. @searchengine27

Comment: @brianpck sorry about that, I have edited the question to include more detail on input & expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement your program.

Note:

- You must use `int()` to convert strings to integers
- I would separate the validation from the computation, but use the same regular expression in both cases.
- I would use a dictionary, not code, to hold the values of metals.
- By using a character class for the metal, I only have to call `re.findall()` once.
- My regular expression allows for a richer set of inventory strings, for example `"10g 10g 10g"` represents 30 gold pieces.

```
import re

money_from_string_pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)([gsc])")


def is_money_from_string_valid(s):
    return not money_from_string_pattern.sub("", s).strip()


def money_from_string(s):
    value = {'g': 10000, 's': 100, 'c': 1}
    inventory = money_from_string_pattern.findall(s)
    return sum(int(amount) * value[metal] for amount, metal in inventory)

assert money_from_string("11g 22s 33c") == 112233
assert money_from_string("11g") == 110000
assert money_from_string("11g 11g") == 220000

assert is_money_from_string_valid("11g 22s 33c") == True
assert is_money_from_string_valid("11g") == True
assert is_money_from_string_valid("11g 11g") == True

assert is_money_from_string_valid("11 g 22s 33c") == False
assert is_money_from_string_valid("11g 22q") == False
assert is_money_from_string_valid("stackoverflow.com") == False
```

Answer (score -1):

If the value returned is `None`, you can simply check for none and replace it with `0`. This seems apt to what your are trying to do.

```
def money_from_string(s):
    gold = re.search("([0-9]+)g", s)
    silver = re.search("([0-9]+)s", s)
    copper = re.search("([0-9]+)c", s)
    if str(gold) in 'None':
        gold = 0
    if str(silver) in 'None':
        silver = 0
    if str(copper) in 'None':
        copper = 0
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+g", "", s)
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+s", "", s)
    s = re.sub("[0-9]+c", "", s)
    assert (len(s.strip()) == 0) # should be 0

    return ((gold.group() * 10000 + silver.group() * 100 + copper.group())
```

Comment: Yeah, and returning the message wasn't useful because it wouldn't help the `gold.group()`. Thanks.

Comment: if str(gold) in 'None' will not work as 'None' will be treated like a an array.  gold.group() will return a string with the letter 'g' in it when it does exist and cannot be multiplied by 10000